# vb basic text is not a member of double

Tags: vb.net, vba, casting, double

I have a problem of conversion. When I write `txta1 = txta1.Text`, it shows "text is not a member of double." I'm not sure why, can someone explain this to me?

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        Dim treatments As String
        Dim ssb, ssw, msb, msw, sigmaA, sigmaB, sigmaC, sigmaabc, squaresigmaA, squaresigmaB, squaresigmaC, squaresigmaabc, f As Double
        Dim txta1, txta2, txta3, txta4, txta5, txtb1, txtb2, txtb3, txtb4, txtb5, txtc1, txtc2, txtc3, txtc4, txtc5 As Double

        'Data Input
        txta1 = txta1.Text



        treatments = lblTreatments.Text


        'Calaculation
        sigmaA = txta1 + txta2 + txta3 + txta4 + txta5
        sigmaB = txtb1 + txtb2 + txtb3 + txtb4 + txtb5
        sigmaC = txtc1 + txtc2 + txtc3 + txtc4 + txtc5
        sigmaabc = sigmaA + sigmaB + sigmaC



        squaresigmaA = txta1 ^ 2 + txtb2 ^ 2 + txtb3 ^ 2 + txtb4 ^ 2 + txtb5 ^ 2
        squaresigmaB = txtb1 ^ 2 + txtb2 ^ 2 + txtb3 ^ 2 + txtb4 ^ 2 + txtb5 ^ 2
        squaresigmaC = txtc1 ^ 2 + txtc2 ^ 2 + txtc3 ^ 2 + txtc4 ^ 2 + txtc5 ^ 2
        squaresigmaabc = squaresigmaA + squaresigmaB + squaresigmaC
        ssb = ((sigmaA) ^ 2 / 5 + (sigmab) ^ 2 / 5 + (sigmac) ^ 2 / 5) - (sigmaabc) ^ 2 / 15
        ssw = squaresigmaabc - ((sigmaA) ^ 2 / 5 + (sigmab) ^ 2 / 5 + (sigmac) ^ 2 / 5)
        msb = ssb / (3 - 1)
        msw = ssw / (15 - 1)
        f = msb / msw

        'Data output
        lblSSB.Text = ssw
        lblSSW.Text = ssw
        lblMSB.Text = msb
        lblMSW.Text = msw
        lblF.Text = f
    End Sub
```

Comment: Okay, so it looks like you're calculating an ANOVA for 3 treatment levels and 5 cases per treatment.  Life will be easier for you and your user(s) if you get this information from a separate file or at least from a grid or some multi-line text entry boxes.  Then you can get the input, split it by line, and operate on it as lists instead of having to hardcode the number of cases and mention each case explicitly in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the compiler is trying to tell you, you declared `txta1` as a `Double`, which has no `Text` property.

You should choose different names for your controls and your local variables.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared txta1 as a Double in line 4.  I assume you also have a TextBox called txta1 on your form.  Use a different name like txta1Value for the Double, so it doesn't clash with the name of the TextBox.  Then you can say

```
txta1Value = Double.Parse(txta1.Text)
```

(This will blow up if someone types something other than a valid Double; how you want to deal with that is up to you.)

Comment: Then suggest `Double.TryParse`!